# After distributing Android as an app bundle, the app is automatically closed due to an app crash when running the app

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, logcat

I'm using react-native with Android.

After distributing Android as an app bundle, the app is automatically closed due to an app crash when running the app.

If I distribute it as an apk file, the app runs well.

However, if the abb file is successfully built with the gradlew bundleRelease command and then deployed to Google and the app is run, the app is automatically closed.

**This is a logcat error.**

```
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.453 6938-27625/? E/pageboostd: active launch start : app comcookingrn
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.454 1011-6254/? E/ActivityTaskManager: TouchDown intent received, starting ActiveLaunch
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.454 6938-27625/? E/pageboostd: comcookingrn, amt 4696304 scnt 2 fcnt 0
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.455 6938-27625/? E/pageboostd: comcookingrn, amt 0 scnt 2 fcnt 0
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.455 6938-27625/? E/pageboostd: active launch end : app comcookingrn data_amount 4696304
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.470 27360-27360/? E/com.cookingrn: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.487 23866-23917/? E/nightwatch-target: lmkd signal waiters
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.527 511-511/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1626756997.521:5296889): avc:  granted  { execute } for  pid=27360 comm="com.cookingrn" path="/data/data/com.cookingrn/lib-0/libc++_shared.so" dev="sda33" ino=1181052 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c186,c258,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c186,c258,c512,c768 tclass=file SEPF_SM-G977N_11_0010 audit_filtered
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.527 511-511/? E/audit: type=1300 audit(1626756997.521:5296889): arch=c00000b7 syscall=222 success=yes exit=479864037376 a0=6fba202000 a1=db770 a2=5 a3=12 items=0 ppid=537 pid=27360 auid=4294967295 uid=10698 gid=10698 euid=10698 suid=10698 fsuid=10698 egid=10698 sgid=10698 fsgid=10698 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="com.cookingrn" exe="/system/bin/app_process64" subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c186,c258,c512,c768 key=(null)
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.527 511-511/? E/audit: type=1327 audit(1626756997.521:5296889): proctitle="com.cookingrn"
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.529 511-511/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1626756997.525:5296890): avc:  granted  { execute } for  pid=27360 comm="com.cookingrn" path="/data/data/com.cookingrn/lib-0/libfb.so" dev="sda33" ino=1181053 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c186,c258,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c186,c258,c512,c768 tclass=file SEPF_SM-G977N_11_0010 audit_filtered
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.558 6938-6938/? E/pageboostd: Received HALT command code 2
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.579 1011-6929/? E/FreecessController: can't read /acct/uid_10217/pid_9782/cgroup.procs/acct/uid_10217/pid_9782/cgroup.procs: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.579 1011-6929/? E/FreecessController: can't read /acct/uid_10217/pid_9782/cgroup.procs/acct/uid_10217/pid_9782/cgroup.procs: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.612 1011-6207/? E/PkgPredictorService-Collector: record changed bt=0  wifi=1 screen=0
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.665 571-571/? E/HYPER-HAL: [SysfsControlManager.cpp]writeSysfs(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/kernel/ems/energy_weight
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.665 571-571/? E/HYPER-HAL: [SysfsControlManager.cpp]writeSysfs(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/kernel/ems/energy_weight
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.694 626-1577/? E/NativeCustomFrequencyManager: [NativeCFMS] BpCustomFrequencyManager::acquire()
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.739 27360-27670/? E/unknown:ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext: mJSIModulePackage null
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.741 27360-27670/? E/unknown:DisabledDevSupportManager: Caught exception
                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(Unknown Source:2)
                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(Unknown Source:10)
                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(Unknown Source:18)
                    at com.facebook.react.r.q(Unknown Source:264)
                    at com.facebook.react.r.c(Unknown Source:0)
                    at com.facebook.react.r$e.run(Unknown Source:68)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.741 27360-27670/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
                Process: com.cookingrn, PID: 27360
                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(Unknown Source:2)
                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(Unknown Source:10)
                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(Unknown Source:18)
                    at com.facebook.react.r.q(Unknown Source:264)
                    at com.facebook.react.r.c(Unknown Source:0)
                    at com.facebook.react.r$e.run(Unknown Source:68)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.782 6285-6322/? E/TaskStackListenerAbstract: onTaskSnapshotChanged called by Binder.getCallingPid() 0 android.app.ITaskStackListener$Stub.onTransact:587 android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal:1195 android.os.Binder.execTransact:1159 <bottom of call stack> 
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.802 6938-6938/? E/pageboostd: Received HALT command code 2
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.827 571-571/? E/HYPER-HAL: [SysfsControlManager.cpp]writeSysfs(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/kernel/ems/energy_weight
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.827 571-571/? E/HYPER-HAL: [SysfsControlManager.cpp]writeSysfs(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/kernel/ems/energy_weight
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.908 571-618/? E/HYPER-HAL: [Request.cpp]acquire(): Request:: id : 535118, No Resource to set
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.977 626-1528/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [Application Error: com.cookingrn#0](id:2720002cbe0,api:0,p:-1,c:626) disconnect: not connected (req=1)
            2021-07-20 13:56:37.988 23866-23917/? E/nightwatch-target: lmkd signal waiters
            2021-07-20 13:56:38.008 1011-7732/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{f7dafdb u0 Splash Screen com.cookingrn EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5251 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5232 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5623 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$01bPtngJg5AqEoOWfW3rWfV7MH4.accept:2 java.util.ArrayList.forEach:1262 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.onAnimationFinished:7162 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.doAnimationFinished:2626 
            2021-07-20 13:56:38.022 626-1528/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [com.cookingrn/com.cookingrn.MainActivity$_27360#0](id:2720002cbde,api:0,p:-1,c:626) disconnect: not connected (req=1)
            2021-07-20 13:56:38.052 626-6811/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [com.cookingrn/com.cookingrn.MainActivity$_27360#1](id:2720002cbdf,api:0,p:-1,c:626) disconnect: not connected (req=1)
            2021-07-20 13:56:38.062 27360-27360/? E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.cookingrn.MainActivity has leaked window DecorView@a30abf5[MainActivity] that was originally added here
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:1049)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:1023)
                    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:450)
                    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:114)
                    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:505)
                    at org.devio.rn.splashscreen.c$a.run(Unknown Source:51)
                    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:7145)
                    at org.devio.rn.splashscreen.c.e(Unknown Source:15)
                    at com.cookingrn.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:3)
                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8198)
                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8182)
                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3765)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: Hi, have you managed to solved it?

Answer (score 0):

```
2021-07-20 13:56:38.062 27360-27360/? E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.cookingrn.MainActivity has leaked window DecorView@a30abf5[MainActivity] that was originally added here.
```

From that line, I understand you're trying to start a new activity while there is still something running, and so it's leaking from the old activity to the new one.

I think it's the dialog that you show here.

```
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:505)
```

Dismissing the dialog should solve your problem.